# Macintosh HD can't be opened because the original file can't be found

Tags: macos, finder, ssd, high-sierra

I'm getting the "Macintosh HD can't be opened because the original file can't be found" error when trying to open Macintosh HD from the sidebar of Finder.

Happening since I installed macOS High Sierra. (I'm using a 2010 MacBook Pro with 256GB SSD)

How do I fix that? How can I open that directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens when you click on the Macintosh HD icon on the Desktop?

Try dragging the Macintosh HD icon out from the sidebar, then drag the Macintosh HD icon from the Desktop into the sidebar to recreate it.

Comment: whenever I try to open it from the sidebar, the error window appears

Comment: So even after you dragged out the old icon, and dragged in a new icon, you still get the error message?

Comment: after pulling it out and messing with the preferences a bit, it works, thanks

Comment: If you add a little detail about what preferences you manipulated, it will help the next person seeking this answer.

Comment: instead of dragging the Macintosh HD folder back to the sidebar, I added my home folder from the Sidebar preferences under Finder Preferences.

Answer (score 3):

With the newest version of Mac system, I found that "Macintosh HD" is not there anymore. This maybe the root cause of the popped out message.

You can use "Devices->YOUR_MAC_NAME" instead of "Macintosh HD". They have the same function.

The following is the screenshot of Finder->Preference->Sidebar. From it we can see that "Macintosh HD" is not there any more.
[image: Finder preference sidebar screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps to access "Macintosh HD" again as you originally had it on your Mac:

1. Open Finder and press <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd>
2. Open Sidebar option.
3. Add your device name (Eg:- "John's MacBook Air").
4. Now, go back to the Finder startup window.
5. Click on Macintosh HD, and simply drag it into the sidebar under "Favorites" option.